# Why doesn't grep -lv work?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to print out the name of a file if and only if it does not contain the string `foo`. However, if `file` contains `foo` and I run this

```
grep -lv 'foo' file
```

`file`  is outputted. Why does this happen and what can I do to work around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-v` means to match any *line* that doesn't match the pattern. So `-lv` means to list any file that contains any line that doesn't match the pattern. That's not the same as a file where *none* of the lines match the pattern.

Use the `-L` option to list all files that don't have any match for the pattern.

```
grep -L 'foo' file
```

> `-L, --files-without-match`
>   Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no  output  would  normally  have  been  printed.   The
>                 scanning will stop on the first match.

Don't use `-v` with this. `-L` already inverts which files are listed, and `-v` inverts the way lines are matched, so `-Lv` is the same as `-l`.

Answer (score 6):

`grep -lv` means: list every file that contains a line that does not match.

You're looking for `grep -L`.

```
grep -L 'foo' file
```

Comment: `grep -Lv 'foo' file` seems to output nothing even if `file` doesn't contain `foo`.

Comment: don't include the v flag

Comment: @JamesKo `-v` is undoing the behavior of `-L`.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks to all of you for clarifying. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you should remove -v option, because it means it will omit the text which is given in any line. So you should try:

```
grep -L 'foo' Input_file
```

Also if you want to know all the files which are having string(foo) in a directory or etc then you could try following too.

```
grep -L 'foo' /path/to/files/*.txt
```

An example of grep -L where it will print all the .txt file names which have string foo in them.

**EDIT:** If in case you are interested in awk solution, you could try following too.

```
awk 'val{close(val)} FNR==1{val=FILENAME} /Var/{;print FILENAME;nextfile}' *.txt
```